# Adding equal and opposite vectors in polar coordinates without transforming into cartesian

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vectors

Suppose that you have two force vectors, $\vec{F_{1}}$ and $\vec{F_{2}}$ in polar coordinates such that they have equal magnitude and opposite angles, $\theta$ as defined below.

$$ \vec{F_{1}}  = r\hat{r}+\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{\theta}$$
$$ \vec{F_{2}}  = r\hat{r}+\frac{5\pi}{4}\hat{\theta}$$

We can assume from symmetry that the total force, $\vec{F_{Total}} = 0$.

Is there a way to show this using only polar coordinates and without resorting to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: $\vec{F}_{Total}$ is not equal zero

Comment: 'r'  has units of length, 'theta' is unitless, so you cannot add those items.   The (+) in those formulae are suggestive, but  not expressive, of the situation.

Comment: You probably meant something like $F=re^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}$ or $re^{\frac{5\pi}{4}i}$, but this can just be expressed as $\vec{F}_1 = |F|\cos(\pi/4)\hat{r} + |F|\sin(\pi/4)\hat{\theta}$ and $\vec{F}_2 = |F|\cos(5\pi/4)\hat{r} + |F|\sin(5\pi/4)\hat{\theta}$, in which case they do, quite obviously, add to zero.

Comment: @Whit3rd You can add them in the linear algebra sense that they form a linear combination, but the expression cannot be simplified as the quantities are of different dimensions

Comment: To the OP: what do you mean by $\hat{\theta}$? That is where your confusion lies.

Comment: see this link, I think this was already discussed somehow. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365622/adding-two-polar-vectors

Comment: The OP means the same thing that Griffiths means. There is nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: Let me expand since there seems to be some confusion (maybe perhaps too on my part).  If I have an object at the origin of the coordinate system and two forces are applied one at 45 degrees and one at 225 degrees the net force on the object will be zero if the magnitudes of the forces are the same. This was inspired by thinking about problem 2.1 in Griffith's E&M.  Is there a way to satisfactorily solve either problem without resorting to a coordinate conversion to cartesian.

Comment: @RCPhysics Perhaps your expansion goes well as an edit. Nevertheless, in the fourth edition Griffiths *does* go into a discussion of adding curvilinear coordinates on page $39$. So sometimes $\bf{\hat{r}} + \bf{\hat{r}} = 0$, and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add vectors without a Cartesian
representation, i.e. represented by two-dimensional r/theta coordinates.
One simply can draw an 'r' length line segment in the 'theta'
direction, and, at its apex, append a second 's' length
vector in the 'theta2' direction.   Drafting machines [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_machine) 
with protractor and scale components are an easy way to
accomplish this, and make it easy to decode the resultant
sum.

As for doing it numerically, I'd stick with Cartesian coordinate transformation.   It's  not hard.

Answer (score 0):

The force components are:

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

\begin{align*}
  &\b F_1=r\,\b e_r+\frac{\pi}{4}\b e_\theta\\
 &\b e_r=\begin{bmatrix}
           \cos(\theta) \\
           \sin(\theta) \\
         \end{bmatrix}\quad,
    \b e_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}
           -\sin(\theta) \\
           \cos(\theta) \\
         \end{bmatrix}    \quad ,\b e_r\perp\b e_\theta 
  \end{align*}

with $~\theta\mapsto -\theta$

\begin{align*}
  &\b F_2=r\,\b e_r+\frac{5\pi}{4}\b e_\theta\\
 &\b e_r\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
           \cos(\theta) \\
           -\sin(\theta) \\
         \end{bmatrix}\quad,
    \b e_\theta\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
           \sin(\theta) \\
           \cos(\theta) \\
         \end{bmatrix}    \quad ,\b e_r\perp\b e_\theta
  \end{align*}

thus $~\b F_1-\b F_2\ne \b 0$

[image]